pagestyle doesn't affect on last page
I use 3 page styles : one for title, 2nd for toc , lof, lot and 3rd for document content.
I understood (with many pain) that every chapter/toc/lof/ ... have especial style plain.
And if toc spread on 2 pages, the 1st page will have plain and the next page will have the style which I defined before toc.
In any case that is not good option (for me) to get different styles in the document just because some page is chapter or title of toc....
I overwrite it in this way:
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

As far as I understand,  it just avoid the style plain to overwrite style which was declared before by me.
But other issue I have now , it is with the last page, it doesn't have any style which I defined and has only page number in the middle of the fancyfoot....
What I'm missing ?
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

I can't share my code (confidential and very long with many includes).

Not sure, just give \clearpage before, \end{document} and then try

Another possibility is that you redefine the header style (with \pagestyle) inside a group, for example begin{appendices} ... \pagestyle{something} ... \end{appendices}. In that case the pagestyle gets lost when the group is ended. The solution is then to add a \newpage or \clearpage before the end of the group, or to put the \pagestyle{...} before the beginning of the group. Anyway, it is usually a good idea to do a \newpage or so before changing the pagestyle.

@PietervanOostrum
I have
{\setstretch{1}
\raggedbottom
}
Is it a group ?
But in any case everything inside this.

That is a group, because of the outer { and }. Even if everything is inside it, if there is a \pagestyle inside, try to put a \clearpage before the closing }

I added \clearpage in the end of the group and it solved the issue.
Thanks !

don't set your whole document in a group it greatly increases the memory load on tex.

A good MWE is a small example which deomstrates the problem and anyone can copy and run (no extra files needed).  You should know that \fancypagestyle{plain}{}  replaces \pagestyle{plain} with a call to \pagestyle{fancy}.  Normaly it includes a bunch of fancyhdr commands, but you left that field blank, which would leave the current fancy pagestyle unchanged.
